# Get value soapxml in XDocument

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, soap

I have one result froom webservice and cannot get the value.

```
  string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
  ResultXML = XDocument.Parse(result);
```

and `ResultXML` looks like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <FaxResponse xmlns="http://abc.xyz/">
      <FaxResult>5421266115</FaxResult>
    </FaxResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need `FaxResult` , how can I read it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var doc=new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path\\Sample.xml");
var k = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FaxResult")[0].InnerText;
```